# Deploy Django with SSL without Nginx

Tags: django

Is it possible to deploy a django project without using third party tools like nginx or apache just to serve up https:// webpages? Being forced to setup a reverse proxy or some other web server just to serve https seems a bit overkill.

Comment: It's not "just to serve https". The development server is not suitable for production use. It's slow and possibly buggy. That being said, you can install `django-extensions` and use the `runserver_plus` command to serve https pages using the development server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using of built-in development server (`manage.py runserver`) is a [bad idea](https://vsupalov.com/django-runserver-in-production/#:%7E:text=DO%20NOT%20USE%20THIS%20SERVER,with%20security%20concerns%20in%20mind.) for production environment. But, yes [you can use SSL connection](https://timonweb.com/django/https-django-development-server-ssl-certificate/) even with built-in server
2. Better idea is to use some application server. For example [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html). And yes again, you can serve [SSL connection](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ssl) with gunicorn.
3. Apache or Nginx servers are not `just for https`. These allows you to effectively control other server resources like max number of processes, request/response headers, etc. WEB servers support many features that you can set without writing python code. And that will be more understandable for infra/server engineers.